# Getting "output eDP-1 not found" from xrandr after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10 when I try to change brightness

Tags: wayland, ubuntu-17.10, xrandr, yoga-x1

I have a ThinkPad X1 Yoga (2nd gen) and when running Ubuntu 17.04 I could change the brightness like this:

```
$ xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness .7
```

Now, when I do that under 17.10 I get this:

```
warning: output eDP-1 not found; ignoring
xrandr: Need crtc to set gamma on.
```

When I hit brightness up and down buttons I see the numerical value in this file changing properly:

```
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/brightness
```

But xrandr reports a new label:

```
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND0 connected 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 180mm
   2560x1440     59.96*+
```

I've tried replacing eDP-1 with XWAYLAND0 but it returns 0 with no errors and nothing at all happens to the brightness.

```
$ xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --brightness 0.5
$ echo $?
0
```

Would love some help on getting brightness settings working again.  Right now it's stuck on full brightness all the time, which isn't great for the battery.

Comment: Note you could always choose gnome classic using X11 over the default gnome wayland for the moment. Perhaps these sorts of problems will be addressed in the future and you can try wayland again.

Comment: Note you could always choose gnome classic using X11 over the default gnome wayland for the moment. Perhaps these sorts of problems will be addressed in the future and you can try wayland again.

Answer (score 2):

`xrandr` is made for X11 and won't work on Wayland. At least I'm not aware of any Wayland protocol for this yet (though one could easily be made).

There might be some `gnome-shell` (if that's the compositor you're using) tool for this, though, but I'm not too familiar with gnome.